# Sequence problem dealing with continuity and convergence.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, continuity

I need help in this question. I figured out a way to solve the question but not sure the proof is valid.
     This is the question,

Given $a \in\mathbb{R}$, and a function $f$:$\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, using proof by contrapositive prove that, if for every sequence ${\{x_n}\}$ of real numbers which converges to $a$, we have $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty }f(x_n)=f(a)$, then f is continuous at $a$.

I tried this,

> Assume  $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty }x_n=a$ and $\lim\limits_{x_n\rightarrow a }$ $f(x_n) \neq f(a)$
>         then  $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow a }$ $f(x_n) \not = f(a)$
>
> therefore $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow a }$ $f(x_n) \neq f(a)$ $\implies$ $($
>    $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty }$$x_n=a$ $\implies$ $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow a
>  }$ $f(x_n) \not = f(a)$ $)$

therefore from the contrapositive the above statement is valid.
I am not sure whether this proof is legitimate or should I start from basic epsilon definition of limit to proove this which appears rather more difficult.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I believe, you are trying to prove that $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow a}f(x)=f(a)$.

Comment: yep but using contrapositive proof

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you are trying to prove that $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow a}f(x)=f(a)$ (the necessary and sufficient condition for continuity in $\mathbb{R}$).

Then, your proof is incorrect. We don't have $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow a}{f(x)}$ in the first place, to be precise the existence of the limit.

Comment: so that means we first need to prove the existence of the limit as well

Comment: @Dulanga: Yes, you need to.

Comment: ahaaa @boywholived i got it thankz a lot!!!!!